# Question about an exercises from the text: Sets for Mathematics in regards to Coseparator and discriminate generalized elements.

Tags: category-theory

The following is taken from Sets for Mathematics by Lawvere

> Definition 1:  An object $S$ in a category $C$ is a $\textbf{separator}$ if and only if whenever
>
> $${\stackrel{\small{X}\stackrel{\small\small f_1}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\small{Y}}{\small\small f_2}}{\stackrel{\stackrel{}{\stackrel{}{}}{}}{}},$$
>
> are arrows of $C$ then
>
> $(\forall x[S\xrightarrow{x}X\Longrightarrow f_1 x=f_2 x])\Longrightarrow [f_1=f_2]$

> Definition 2:  An object V is a $\textbf{cospearator}$ if for any $A$ and for any parallel pair
>
> $${\stackrel{\small{T}\stackrel{\small\small a_0}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\small{A}}{\small\small a_1}}{\stackrel{\stackrel{}{\stackrel{}{}}{}}{}}$$
>
> (of "generalized elements")
>
> $(\forall \phi[A\xrightarrow{\phi}V\Longrightarrow \phi a_0=\phi a_1])\Longrightarrow [a_0=a_1]$
>
> Notice that if $V$ is a coseparator, then $a_0\neq a_1$ entails that there is $A\xrightarrow{\phi}V$ with $\phi a_0\neq\phi a_1,$ i.e. $V$ can discriminate elements.  By what we have said here, neither $V=0$ nor $V=1$ can coseparate.
>
> Exercise:  Use the fact that $1$ is a separator in the category of abstract sets to show that (in that category), if $V$ can discriminate elements, then it can discriminate generalized elements.

$\textbf{Points of confusion:}$

I am not sure how to go about the exercise because I don't know the subtle differences between when it says $V$ can discriminate elements versus $V$ being a coseparator.  It seems to me that if i can discriminate elements for being in a coseparator, then it can automatically discriminate generalized elements?

From definition 1, we have $(\forall x[1\xrightarrow{x}X\Longrightarrow f_1 x=f_2 x])\Longrightarrow [f_1=f_2]$ and $V$ can discriminate elements, that means V is being in a coseparator, then again, by definition 1, letting $A=1$, $X=V$ and $\phi=x$, and also from definition 2 with $a_0=f_1$ and $a_1=f_2$, then $f_1\neq f_2$ there is $1\xrightarrow{\phi}V$ implying $\phi f_1\neq\phi f_2.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is meant by “discriminate *generalised* elements”? The definition of “discriminate elements” already only refers to generalised elements

Comment: @FShrike in the case of $V$ being able to discriminate elements, it is referring to being able to discriminate pairs of maps as elements with common codomain? Also what is the difference between in a coseparator and being able to discriminate elements?

Comment: You haven’t said what Lawvere means by ‘discriminate generalised elements’ and how this notion differs from ‘discriminate elements’. It might help to define this ‘category of abstract sets’

Comment: @FShrike he did not define "discriminate generalized elements".  I copied it verbatim from the book.

Comment: I guess that "V discriminate elements" is just introduced in the paragraph you cited as a synonymous description of the coseparator proeprty.  Also I guess that it refers already to generalized elements (arbitrary domain) and not only to elements (domain 1).

So the exercise asks: if $V$ satisfies
$(\forall \phi\colon A\to V: \phi a_0 = \phi a_1)\Rightarrow (a_0=a_1)$
for all $a_0,a_1\colon 1\to A$ then it also satisfies the above
for all $a_0,a_1\colon T\to A$.

Comment: @MarcOlschok is what I wrote remotely okay considered as s solution.  I thought if @V@ can discriminate elements, then it is being in a coseparator and hence automatically can discriminate generalized elements.  When it comes to anything involving parallel arrows in category theory, I searched for concrete math examples, it is hard to figure out what those pair of parallel arrows correspond to in that particular math context.  Also from $(\forall \phi\colon A\to V: \phi a_0 = \phi a_1)\Rightarrow (a_0=a_1)$, equivalently that would mean $a_0\neq a_1$ and so doesn't that....

Comment: @MarcOlschok ... say anything about $V$ being able to discriminate the generalised elements or the pair of mappings having common domain $T$?

Comment: An element of $A$ is a map $1\to A$. A generalized element is a map $T\to A$ for an arbitrary domain $T$. So it is possible that some $V$ can discriminate elements, but cannot discriminate generalized elements. E.g. whenever there are not enough elements, like in the category of groups.

Comment: Just a hint: rewrite the conditions via contraposition:           $[a_0 \neq a_1] \Longrightarrow \exists \phi\colon A\to V: \phi a_0 \neq \phi a_1$

Comment: @MarcOlschok can I ask what do you mean by whenever there are not enough elements?  I thought for the purpose of the exercise, we have a pair of parallel maps which are the generalized elements?  Actually, when it says $V$ can discriminate elements or discriminate generalized elements, is it because of or referring to $a_0\neq a_1$ or $\phi a_0\neq \phi a_1?$

Comment: @Seth: Consider the category of groups. The trivial group $e$ is the terminal object. But for any group $G$ there is only one group homomorphism from $e$ to $G$. So every object $H$ can discriminate maps with domain $e$. The abstract core of the exercise is the following: if a category has a separator $S$, then for an object $V$ to be a coseparator, it is enough to test it on maps with domain $S$. That is because if you have two different maps $a_0,a_1\colon T\to A$, then there is a map $x\colon S\to T$ such that $a_0x,a_1x\colon S\to A$ are still two different maps.